# Weird bug using xamp and phpmailer

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer, httpserver

So i have phpmailer in my website , it's working properly but i'm experiencing a weird bug when i put attachments into the mail if i put a 24kb attatchment , when this code has to be executed , the browser hangs , trying to load localhost (xamp website) and i can't actually enter the website it hangs on "connecting" i've tried attaching 0kb files to the email and it works so im guessing this has to do  with the PDF File i'm trying to attach rather than with the code , anyway , this is what im doing :

```
require_once("../../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer;

// Debug para ver errores 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               
//hacemos que  PHPMailer use SMTP.
$mail->isSMTP();            
//direccion                          
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
//poner verdadero para requerir autorizacion
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
//Usuario y contraseña   
$mail->Username = "rakall66@gmail.com";                 
$mail->Password = "****";                           
//If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                           
//Set TCP port to connect to 
$mail->Port = 587;                                   

$mail->From = "rakall66@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "No responder - Informacion Pago";
$receptor="testingfield1@hotmail.com";
$mail->addAddress($receptor, "El que recibe");

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Pago en Vidya";
$mail->Body = "<i>Usted ".$login_session."  ha realizado un pago en Vidya </i>";
$mail->AltBody = "Version en texto plano";
$mail->AddAttachment("../../facturas/factura.pdf","nombre");
//$mail->AddAttachment("../../facturas/factura.pdf","nombre");
if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo " error";
}
```

Comment: Any entries appear in the error log when the browser gives up on hanging? Or maybe even during the hang?

Comment: change this `echo " error";` to this `echo "Success";`

Comment: as @Abdulla noticed, your last part is corrupted. Then, if the problem doesn't come from "error" displayed, did you add log to see which line is stuck in a loop ?

Comment: what's that going to do? i tried waiting for the browser to do something and after a while a php error appears , but the line it says has nothing that can explain the hang

Comment: check Apache log files

Comment: * upload completely sent off: 601 out of 601 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2015 13:11:09 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-PAYPAL-OPERATION-NAME: DoExpressCheckoutPayment
< X-PAYPAL-API-RC: 
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 858
< Paypal-Debug-Id: e9b5fc67812c0
< Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dappdispatcher_apit%26TIME%3D3977917014; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< 
* Closing connection 0

Comment: that's in the error log , but i think it's not an error , that was the last time i uploaded a 0kb file

Comment: this is what appears after a while Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\session.php on line 20  this is the file http://pastebin.com/HSnsmJBa

Comment: its a timeout. You need to change the  max_execution_time parameter from 30 to 60 or a bit higher you can find it in C:\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini line 244

Comment: will try if that way it works , i'll edit this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the code's location , it was on an if that made the hole document loop , until timing out after those 30 seconds.